# HttpTestingController.expectOne can't see my request, but it is open in afterEach() method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing a unit test to test my service which is calling rest API. expectOne() fails to find my request: *Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/stat/estimation-graph", found none.*

I tried different overloads of expectOne(), such as:

```
httpMock.expectOne(url)
httpMock.expectOne({method: 'GET', url: url})
httpMock.expectOne(res => res.method === 'GET' && res.url === url)
```

Also, I tried changing URL so that is contains parameters ('http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/stat/estimation-graph?battleCount=100&winCount=50') but with no luck.

Lastly, I opened a Chrome console with Karma test results and I found that my API can't be called due to CORS policy. I Fixed that also.

**My .spec.ts file:**

```
// imports..

describe('StatProviderService', () => {
    let injector: Injector;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    let statService: StatProviderService;
    beforeEach(() => 
    {
        injector = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                StatProviderService,
            ],
        });
        httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
        statService = injector.get(StatProviderService);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        httpMock.verify();
    });

    it('should work', () => {
        let response;
        let url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/stat/estimation-graph';

        statService.getEstimationGraphData( 100, 50 )
          .subscribe(res => {
            response = res;
          });

        const req = httpMock.expectOne(url);
        req.flush(response);
    });
});
```

**My service class:**

```
// imports...

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StatProviderService {
    // private variables

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    private baseApiUrl(endpoint?: string) {
        return `${this.env.apiUrl}/${this.apiVer}/${endpoint}`;
    }

    getEstimationGraphData(battlecount: number, winCount: number): Observable<IEstimationGraphPoint[]> {
        return this.http.get<IEstimationGraphPoint[]>(`${this.baseApiUrl(this.graphDataEndpoint)}/?battleCount=${battlecount}&winCount=${winCount}`);
    }
}
```

The Karma result window is telling me that it can't locate the open request:

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/stat/estimation-graph", found none.
```

**But** after adding the *httpMock.verify()* in the *afterEach()* I got the next error:

```
Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/stat/estimation-graph/
```

So looks like the request is called, but later than expected. As far as I subscribed to *getEstimationGraphData()* it should be called synchronously, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are appending the params with the URL in your service, the `HttpTestingController` expects the test URL also to contain the params. Instead of creating the URL with params in your service, pass them as `HttpParams`.

```
getEstimationGraphData(battlecount: number, winCount: number): Observable<IEstimationGraphPoint[]> {
  return this.http.get<IEstimationGraphPoint[]>(this.baseApiUrl(this.graphDataEndpoint), {
    params: {
      battleCount: battlecount.toString(),
      winCount: winCount.toString()
    }
  });
}
```

Now, in your spec file, you need to use a custom function to check for the url. Use the below code to test for the url:

```
const req = httpMock.expectOne((request: HttpRequest<any>) => {
  return request.url === url;
});
```

`request.url` will contain the url without the params. The actual URL with params will be in `request.urlWithParams` if in case you need to check the params as well.

You might also need to remove `HttpClientModule` from your spec file. You just need `HttpClientTestingModule`.